# Local Git branch has diverged from origin following an interactive rebase

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I have a local branch (`CRM-ayrshireminis`) that has a couple of commits on it that I have pushed to the origin (`origin/CRM-ayrshireminis`). This branch was created from the `develop` branch about one week ago, on which there have been one weeks worth of work from other collaborators.

What I want to do is rebase the latest code from `origin/develop` into my feature branch `CRM-ayrshireminis`.

What I done was:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git rebase -i develop CRM-ayrshireminis
```

I had two commits, so I squashed them into one and then quit out. I got the message saying `Rebasing (2/2)`, so it seemed fine...

```
[crmpicco@dev53 ayrshireminis]$ git status
# On branch CRM-ayrshireminis
# Your branch and 'origin/CRM-ayrshireminis' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

Is there any way for me to rebase the commits from develop into my branch and squash my two commits into one as I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to rebase the commits from develop into my branch

You're doing this backwards. You're moving the branch `develop` on top of your branch, which necessarily causes it to diverge from `origin/develop`. If your intent is to include new commits from develop in your branch, what you actually want is to rebase your branch on top of `develop`:

```
git fetch
git checkout CRM-ayrshireminis
git rebase -i origin/develop
git push -f origin CRM-ayrshireminis
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is that last command correct? `git rebase -i origin/develop`. I can't say i've seen origin branches be referenced when i've researched this. If I got a pull on develop and then `git rebase -i develop` would that essentially be the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that would be the same. Rebasing onto `origin/develop` means you don't have to worry about checking out `develop` and `git pull`ing first. If you're already on your own branch, you can just run `git fetch; git rebase origin/develop` and be done with it - no branch switching at all.

Comment: I have just tried this and I am experiencing the _exact_ same issue, e.g. `Your branch and origin/CRM-ayrshireminis have diverged`. I am already on my feature branch as you said and done a `git fetch` followed by a `git rebase -i origin/develop`, but it has left me with the same problem. I can't understand why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: @crmpicco The *entire purpose* of this command is to diverge your two branches. Once you're done rebasing, you need to `git push -f` to overwrite the state of the remote branch with your own branch. If you don't want your histories to diverge, you cannot use rebase.