# Issue with exorbitant number of conflicts following a second git rebase on origin branch

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I am fairly new to the concept of rebasing with Git, and I have been following the guidance from [another SO poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412444/local-git-branch-has-diverged-from-origin-following-an-interactive-rebase) by doing this:

```
git fetch
git checkout CRM-my-feature-branch
git rebase -i origin/develop
git push -f origin CRM-my-feature-branch
```

This has generally worked well for me. I done this in mid-May to bring `CRM-my-feature-branch` up to date with `origin/develop` which other developers are working on.

However, I have just tried to do the same thing again and I have been hit with a vast number of conflicts. Now, conflicts are fine but some files seem to almost be in a permanent state of conflict. For example, commit 2 will show as a conflict of commit 1 so rather than git realising that commit 2 comes after commit 1 - it shows as a conflict.

Is this a symptom of rebasing on top of a branch that I have previously rebased on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git `rebase` is still fairly confusing to get my head around, but I believe this has been caused by attempting to rebase commits onto a branch where they already existed.

e.g.

Branch develop -> CRM-my-feature-branch

They are C1, C2 and C3 on develop

and CRM1, CRM2 and CRM3 (commits on CRM-my-feature-branch)

a `git merge` of C1, C2 and C3 -> CRM-my-feature-branch is *fine*

however a `git rebase` of CRM-my-feature-branch onto develop and I am trying to rebase commits C1, C2 and C3 onto a branch where they already existed.

HTH someone in future.